# Installing dlib on raspberry pi3

Tags: python, shared-libraries, opencv

I've been trying to install dlib on my raspberry pi 3 since past 2 days, but every time end up with a frozen screen. The pi is running on the latest raspbian and
and everything seems like up-to-date, then what could be the issue??

Comment: What command did you try? Does terminal show any error?

Comment: With `apt list *dlib*` I cannot find any relevant package in the repository. The nearest seems to bee **libdlib18**. Do you mean this library for "*C++ toolkit for machine learning and computer vision*"? Where do you get your **dlib** from? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.